# ¿Por qué se presenta el error "firebase.database is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Tengo el siguiente código en JavaScript que incrusto en mi documento html con el que intento hacer conexión a mi base de datos en FireBase. Antes de incrustarlo he agregado el SDK en el html para este servicio.

En el archivo js agrego la configuracion e inicializo pero al intentar crear una referencia para leer me marca error **"firebase.database is not a function"**

```
var task = firebase.database().ref("usuarios");
```

**Código html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Verificaciones</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Aquí debería haber algo...</h2>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <p id="perfilNombre">nombre:</p>
    <br>
    <p id="perfilEmail">email:</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Script js**

```
    var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxm",
    projectId: "pruebas",
    storageBucket: "pruebas-",
    messagingSenderId: "111",
    appId: "1:123123:web:123123",
    measurementId: "G-3"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var task = firebase.database().ref("usuarios");
var perfilNombre = document.getElementById("perfilNombre");
var perfilEmail = document.getElementById("perfilEmail");
```

Comment: Creo que deberías de cambiar el nombre de tu pregunta ya que si solo quieres saber que significa **firebase.database is not a function** quiere decir que eso que tienes declarado no es una función , lo puedes cambiar por **Por que se presenta el siguiente error y que significa.**

Comment: Cuando generaste los CND para poner firebase no te dieron una url para database asi : **<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente en el archivo index.js, parece que no esta haciendo referencia al nodo o child creado en la base de datos:

```
 var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCfgT9eCcC1wLVSCZAMjtsIVlV4EKbL4WE",
    authDomain: "pruebas-18649.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://pruebas-18649.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "pruebas-18649",
    storageBucket: "pruebas-18649.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "742626874887",
    appId: "1:742626874887:web:94bc1a052162c7e7127ca2",
    measurementId: "G-H3QBPLBSH7"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

const dbref=firebase.database().ref().child('usuarios');

dbref.on('value',function(snapshot){

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

        console.log(childSnapshot.key)

        console.log(childSnapshot.val())
    })

})
```

Y en el archivo html modifique esta línea:

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado correctamente

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

Necesitas agregar el script de firebase-database para poder usar la base de datos(agrega esto y se arreglara):

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Tambien puedes usar

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

si solo quieres usar un script

Answer (score 0):

Cuando en javascript usas una llamada con la sintaxis `firebase.database()` le estas diciendo que *database* es efectivamente una función, pero seguramente (sí existe en el objeto *firebase*, es una "propiedad") y debes hacer la llamada como `firebase.database`.

Un ejemplo de este error sería el siguiente, al intentar averiguar el tamaño de un array:

```
var arr = [1,2];
console.log(arr.length());
```

La consola muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> VM200:2 Uncaught TypeError: arr.length is not a function
>       at :2:17

En este caso el script correcto sería:

```
var arr = [1,2];
console.log(arr.length);
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación